# Dynamic text in SAS VA (Visual Analytics)

Tags: sas, sas-visual-analytics

I am making a nice dashboard. I have Geo-map with projects. When a user clicks on a particular project it will take the user to a detailed page about the project. I want to give this page (sheet) a dynamic title.

For example:  The user clicks on the GEO map on the project in Aalst, he will be redirected to the detail page with a tittle "Costs and revenues for Project in Aalst".

Pictures of my dashboard:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y96NY.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIBP0.png)

Comment: Post this on communities.sas.com. There are more VA users there n

Answer (score 2):

I was working with VA 7.1 and there wasn't any way to parameterized text fields in VA reports. I've heard SAS wants to add this function in future release and at this moment you have to find a different way to put dynamic label on the report.

For example you can put a flat table with combination of every posible title you need. Then change style parameters  for this table. You can turn off borders and column headers, change table background color, text font size and color, so you can make it looks like as a title field. Then you define filter connection between GEO map and this table, so when you click on the GEO map it will filter single record with correct title.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems to solve the problem. The only problem is that you cannot hide all layout in a list table.